# Capture video of ultrasonography machine through Java application

Tags: java, image, swing, video, capture

1. Could you give me some pointers on how I can get started writing an application in Java that captures/records the video of an ultrasonography machine? Where should I get started?
2. What concept(s)/theory do I need to know before starting to write such a program?

I have had no previous experience working with image/video related software.  Presently, I can write decent Java-based database applications.

The target machine is [GE Logiq 100 Pro](http://www.gehealthcare.com/euen/ultrasound/products/general-imaging/logiq-100-pro/index.html)

Comment: You need to understand the hardware interfaces available on a ultrasonography machine: this is too vendor-specific. Check their documentation. Anyway, if it has an analog video BNC output, it can be connected to a video capture device like a video encoder. If you use an IP based video encoder, you can just stream it like IP video streaming. With this in mind, any Java media framework can now read an IP video streaming.

Comment: This may be closed as too localised/specific. However, can you provide the brand name of the machine? That is probably essential in answering this question.

Comment: @halfer As of now, I don't know the make & model of the machine. However, by tomorrow, I will get to know it, and will post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most modern ultrasound devices would produce digital image data in form regulated by DICOM standard. In theory, this shall be easily interchangeable between different viewers  and hospital information systems (in practice it is not :( )

If they do not produce digital data as DICOM, your only option is to capture analog video stream and digitize it.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda I was hitherto unaware of the terms like DICOM. This standard appears pretty relevant to the task in hand.

Comment: @eee The link provided by you seems pretty useful !:-)

Comment: DICOM is very mature standard and is videly used over the last 12 years. (Though compatibiilty claims are not always correct -  sometimes it allows too wide interpretation of data)

Comment: *"grammar inkvisitionforced me to edit this"*  (polite cough)  Nobody was forcing anything.  You can roll-back the edits to the original if you wish, & I'll just remove my up-vote.  (I'm not prepared to have my up-votes appear on a good answer that is hard to read or understand, is all.)

Comment: It was my own internal grammar inquisition ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - `:-)` at grammar discussion! Bear in mind though that 'digitise' (and all other -ise words) are generally correct. These come from modern British English, whereas the old English -ize form is the correct US English spelling.